# Prove that $\forall d\in \mathbb{N}, f\colon \mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is continuous. (proof verification)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification

Prove that $\forall d\in \mathbb{N}, f\colon \mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is continuous.

---

We want to prove that
$$\forall (a_1,a_2)\in \mathbb{N}^2,\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall (m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2,$$
$$\|(m,n)-(a_1,a_2)\|<\delta\implies \|f(m,n)-f(a_1,a_2)\|<\varepsilon$$
Let $\delta=1$
Case 1: $(m,n)=(a_1,a_2)$
In this case both sides of the implication are true since both sides are equivalent to $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. We conclude that the implication is true for case 1

Case 2: $(m,n)\neq(a_1,a_2)$
The LHS of the implication can be written as
$$(m-a_1)^2+(n-a_2)^2<\delta^2\mid_{\delta=1}\tag{*}$$
but the LHS is a natural number so it can't be less than $1$. We conclude that the LHS of the implication is false. Since $F\implies p$ is always true, we conclude that the implication is true for case 2

The implication being true for all cases, we conclude that $\forall d\in\mathbb{N},\;f\colon \mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is continuous.

---

Has this been proven properlly?

Comment: You have a typo in your first formula: $(a_1, a_2) \in \Bbb{N}^2$ should read $(a_1, a_2) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. Apart from that, your proof is fine except that you should state that you are giving a $\delta$ that works for any $\epsilon$. (You can also abbreviate the proof by treating both cases together: if the LHS of the implication is true, then $(m, n) = (a_1, a_2)$, and if the LHS is false, then the implication is vacuously true.)

Comment: So, you are saying let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then choose $\delta = 1$ since in that case there there is only one point that fulfills $\| (m,n) - (a_1,a_2)\| < \delta$, namely $(m,n) = (a_1,a_2)$. So, you are done. I think case 2 is not needed.

Comment: @RobArthan why $\mathbb{R}^2$? I think it is correct as stated.

Comment: @RobArthan , If I were to change $(a_1,a_2)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ to $(a_1,a_2)\in\mathbb{R}$, then the proof is no longer correct (since LHS of (*) is no longer a natural number), in fact, the original statement would be false

Comment: You are right: that wasn't a typo. The rest of my comment stands.

Comment: If you are giving $\mathbb{N}$ the discrete topology and $\mathbb{N}^2$ the product topology, then the inverse image of $any$ set by $f$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you mean  $\mathbb N^2$ with the usual discrete topology.  But any map out of a discrete space is continuous.